# Yii View, Replacing some database values in CGridView

Tags: yii

I am new with Yii, Sorry if my question might be stupid, I am using CGridView to show some fields of my database in a table:

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Advanced Search','#',array('class'=>'search-button')); ?>
<div class="search-form" style="display:none">
<?php $this->renderPartial('_search',array(
    'model'=>$model,
 )); ?>
</div><!-- search-form -->

<?php 


 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
   'id'=>'show-grid',
   'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
   'filter'=>$model,
   'columns'=>array(
       'id',
       'title',
       'brief',
       'tbl_season_id',
       'on_season',

                array(
                    'name'=>'status',
                    'value'=>'Lookup::item("NewsStatus",$data->status)',
                    'filter'=>  Lookup::items('NewsStatus'),
                ),
        array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
        ),
      )); ?>
    </div>
```

I want to replace some of the values that are shown, for example, the `on_season` field is binary and in the table the values are 0 or 1, I want to change this values to `Yes` and `NO`,

And `tbl_season_id` is a foreign key form another table, I would like to get the name of the season and put it instead of the id which is not understandable by the users.

Comment: For the first: you've to do the same as with 'status' column. Put 'type' property to 'raw' and then you can do whatever you need in the 'value' property (e.g. '$data->on_season? "Yes": "No"').

For the second: create a relation in your model (e.g. called 'season') and then put the relation in the grid column this way: 'season.name'.

Comment: It worked, also can I replace the title values?

Comment: There's a property called 'header' :P For more info about available attributes: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridColumn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer this wiki article for customizing your column values to your heart's content

[Yii Documentataion: cgridview-render-customized-complex-datacolumns](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/278/cgridview-render-customized-complex-datacolumns/)

Just remember that the value property can be an expression string, which is later evaluated for each data of rows. So you have a method call there which can dynamically calculate any value for you depending on the current values of that row.

Answer (score 1):

---

Let you have two table

1): clients 2): projects

---

Relation is a client has many projects.

in model

---

and clients model the relation is (the Client table model name is **Client**)

```
 class Client extends CActiveRecord{
    }
```

and relations() method ;

```
 return array(
      'projects' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Projects', 'clients_id'),
  );
```

---

project model the relation is (the project table model name is **Projects**)

```
      class Projects extends CActiveRecord{
         }
```

and relations() method ;

```
   return array(
          'clients' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Client', 'clients_id')
     );
```

---

**Now**
now you can use the following to get the client_name replace the client_id in proejct table
in CGridView

---

```
  'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
  'columns' => array(
         'id',
          'project_name',
     array(
        'name' => 'client Name',
        'value' => '$data->clients->name',   //where name is Client model attribute 
       ),
    )
```

---

and 
Project view page  in CDetailView you can use the following

```
'data' => $model,
'attributes' => array(
               'id',
              'project_name',
         array(
            'name'=>'Client Name',
            'value'=>$model->clients->name ,
        ),
```

)

---

if you have client relation with company table (a company has many clients )
client model

```
   'company' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Company', 'company_id'),
```

you can also get the company name by following method in 
index (**CGridview**)

```
   array(
      'name' => 'client Name',
    'value' => '$data->clients->company->name', //where name is company model attribute 
    ),
```

and in view  **CDetailView**

```
 array(
    'name'=>'Client Name',
     'value'=>$model->clients->company->name ,
        ),
```

---