# Replacing int to some value without using any widget (e.g CListView or CGridView)

Tags: yii

I have two tables where one attribute is foreign key. I want to display it without using any widgets(e.g CListView or CGridView)
The problem is how to show varchar instead of INT
what I've done in the views/name_folder/index.php  is

```
<table id="box-table-a">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">No</th>
         <th scope="col">Project</th>
         <th scope="col">Contractor</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
     <?php 
    foreach($projectDataProvider->data as $p):?>
    <td><?php echo $p->id;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $p->project_name;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $p->contractor_id;?></td> //How to echo $p->contractor_name;???              
  </tr>
     <?php endforeach;?>    
</tbody>
</tabel>
```

the problem is quite similar to this [Yii View, Replacing some database values in CGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048857/yii-view-replacing-some-database-values-in-cgridview) but in my case I don't want to use any widgets, is that possible?

Comment: do you want to show related some related column, from the foreign keys table?

Answer (score 0):

Please read http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/227/guidelines-for-good-schema-design/
to read about the foreign keys. In your example I think you would need to first specify relation in your project model to foreign key contractor_id.

Like this:

```
public function relations()
{
   return array(
      'contractor' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Contractor', 'contractor_id')
   );
}
```

Once you have specified the relation to another table(Contractor), you can get contractor name by typing

```
$project->contractor->name.
```

Project variable is your project model instance and name is attribute from contractor model.